# VB PDF Program that the user can upload file and save

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf

i have a program that writes data to a PDF file. i would like to add the ability for the program to ask the user what file they would like to upload and when saving it will ask the user what they would like to name it and where they would like to save it. i would also like this program to save two files. the original and the one with the data in it. this is my program so far

''' Public Class Form1

```
''' <summary>
''' Application main form Load event handler
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sender"></param>
''' <param name="e"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ' Load all field names from template PDF
    'ListFieldNames()

    ' Fill the target PDF form with canned values
    FillForm2()

End Sub



''' <summary>
''' List all of the form fields into a textbox.  The
''' form fields identified can be used to map each of the
''' fields in a PDF.
''' </summary>
Private Sub ListFieldNames()

    Dim pdfTemplate As String = "c:\Temp\PDF\RD108ApplicationForTitle.pdf"
    Dim newFile As String = "c:\Temp\PDF\RD108ApplicationForTitle_fw4.pdf"

    ' title the form
    Me.Text += " - " + PdfTemplate

    ' create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
    'Dim pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream( _
                newFile, FileMode.Create))

    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

    ' create and populate a string builder with each of the 
    ' field names available in the subject PDF
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    Dim intFieldNum As Integer = 1
    Dim de As New DictionaryEntry
    For Each de In pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0} - {1}{2}", intFieldNum, de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine))
        pdfFormFields.SetField(de.Key.ToString(), intFieldNum)
        intFieldNum = intFieldNum + 1
    Next

    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = True
    pdfStamper.Close()

    ' Write the string builder's content to the form's textbox
    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
    textBox1.SelectionStart = 0

End Sub


Private Sub FillForm()

    Dim pdfTemplate As String = "c:\Temp\PDF\fw4.pdf"
    Dim newFile As String = "c:\Temp\PDF\Final_fw4.pdf"

    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream( _
                newFile, FileMode.Create))

    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

    ' set form pdfFormFields

    ' The first worksheet and W-4 form
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_01(0)", "1")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_02(0)", "1")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_03(0)", "1")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_04(0)", "8")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_05(0)", "0")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_06(0)", "1")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_07(0)", "16")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_08(0)", "28")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_09(0)", "Franklin A.")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_10(0)", "Benefield")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_11(0)", "532")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_12(0)", "12")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_13(0)", "1234")

    ' The form's checkboxes
    pdfFormFields.SetField("c1_01(0)", "0")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("c1_02(0)", "Yes")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("c1_03(0)", "0")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("c1_04(0)", "Yes")

    ' The rest of the form pdfFormFields
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_14(0)", "100 North Cujo Street")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_15(0)", "Nome, AK  67201")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_16(0)", "9")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_17(0)", "10")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_18(0)", "11")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_19(0)", "Walmart, Nome, AK")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_20(0)", "WAL666")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_21(0)", "AB")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_22(0)", "4321")

    ' Second Worksheets pdfFormFields
    ' In order to map the fields, I just pass them a sequential
    ' number to mark them once I know which field is which, I 
    ' can pass the appropriate value
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_01(0)", "1")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_02(0)", "2")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_03(0)", "3")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_04(0)", "4")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_05(0)", "5")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_06(0)", "6")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_07(0)", "7")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_08(0)", "8")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_09(0)", "9")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_10(0)", "10")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_11(0)", "11")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_12(0)", "12")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_13(0)", "13")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_14(0)", "14")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_15(0)", "15")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_16(0)", "16")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_17(0)", "17")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_18(0)", "18")
    pdfFormFields.SetField("f2_19(0)", "19")

    ' report by reading values from completed PDF
    Dim sTmp As String = "W-4 Completed for " + pdfFormFields.GetField("f1_09(0)") + " " + _
    pdfFormFields.GetField("f1_10(0)")
    MessageBox.Show(sTmp, "Finished")

    ' flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
    ' to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = True

    ' close the pdf
    pdfStamper.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub FillForm2()

    Dim pdfTemplate As String = "c:\Temp\PDF\CalbeeBOL.pdf"
    Dim newFile As String = "c:\Temp\PDF\CableeBOL_fw4.pdf"

    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream( _
                newFile, FileMode.Create))

    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    Dim intFieldNum As Integer = 1
    Dim de As New DictionaryEntry
    For Each de In pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0} - {1}{2}", intFieldNum, de.Key.ToString(), Environment.NewLine))
        pdfFormFields.SetField(de.Key.ToString(), intFieldNum)
        intFieldNum = intFieldNum + 1
    Next

    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
    textBox1.SelectionStart = 0

    ' set form pdfFormFields

    ' The first worksheet and W-4 form

    ' report by reading values from completed PDF
    'Dim sTmp As String = "W-4 Completed for " + pdfFormFields.GetField("f1_09(0)") + " " + _
    'pdfFormFields.GetField("f1_10(0)")
    'MessageBox.Show(sTmp, "Finished")

    ' flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
    ' to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = True

    ' close the pdf
    pdfStamper.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how do i get it to ask the user what file they want to upload and where they would like to save it and name it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384784/using-the-open-file-and-save-file-dialogs-in-vb-net

Comment: SaveFileDialog: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx