# How can I allow the user to select an Excel file and query the selected file in a WinForms application?

Tags: vb.net, excel, winforms

I know how to query a spreadsheet for certain results; that is not the problem. I am having trouble with finding the right approach to allow the user to select the file that should be queried. At this point, I have scrapped my code for this endeavor. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Selecting a file is pretty easy - use an `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: Are there requirements for selecting files e.g. sheets laid out with specific columns within etc.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the advice. That's part of what I was trying. Honestly, I wish I hadn't deleted my code. I was using the `OpenFileDialog` control. In the event handler that handles the `File.Ok` event I was accessing the selected file and attempting to query it, but there was an `InvalidInputException`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the open file and save file dialogs in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384784/using-the-open-file-and-save-file-dialogs-in-vb-net)

Comment: Finding/getting the file is one operation.  Opening it and querying it is another.  Dont glue them together.  How you open and query it  cant be covered in comments.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to setup a datasource to the excel sheet, where you could query then load the data into your forms.
The user could replace this file with another, either through your application or manually.

(without knowing your original approach)
Example:

[excel as datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPkrC.png)

Comment: I appreciate the response. I don't even necessarily need the user to be able to open the Excel file (it would be nice). All I need the user to do is point to the location in his/her file system where the Excel file is located. Then, there is a simple query that finds values that the user has in the file. These values are added to a `Datatable`, then they are put into a `Listbox`. Of course, there are a few more details, but these are the only steps that are necessary to this question.